# Parent-child select dropdown relationships using unobtrusive javascript in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html-select, simple-form, unobtrusive-javascript

I have an application that has a pretty simple parent -> child relationship between a Venue and a Hall(so an Event has a Venue and a Venue has many Halls), in the admin screens I want to be able to select a venue(via an association in a select box) and have it auto-populate(preferably an AJAX JSON request) the halls(in another select box) for that venue.

It occurs to me that this sort of stuff should be either standard or in a gem somewhere, **are there any better options?**

I have attached my current solution

Answer (score -1):

I have had a really good look about and have found: [How to implement dependent dropdowns in Rails 4 with an unobtrusive jQuery script](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2013/12/come-implementare-in-rails-4-delle-dropdown-dipendenti-con-script-jquery-non-intrusivo/)

I have taken this and bastardised it a little to work properly with `chosen` and make it a little simpler, and correct a few bugs:

**_form.haml:**

```
= simple_form_for(@event, ... ) do |f|
  = f.association :hall, collection: @event.venue.halls.order(:name), include_blank: false, input_html: {class: "chosen", 
    data: {linked: "select", 
           linked_parent_id: "event_venue_id",
           linked_collection_path: venue_halls_path(":venue_id:")}}
  = f.association :venue, include_blank: false , :input_html => {class: "chosen"}
```

note that the value and label is optional, the following also works:

```
    data: {linked: "select", 
           linked_parent_id: "event_venue_id",
           linked_collection_path: venue_halls_path(":venue_id:"),
           linked_collection_value: "id",
           linked_collection_label: "name"}
```

**routes.rb** includes the following mapping(via resources):

```
venue_halls_path     GET     /venues/:venue_id/halls(.:format)   halls#index
```

aka

```
...
resources :venues, shallow: true do
  resources :halls
end
...
```

**halls_controller.rb:**

```
...
def index
  @halls = Venue.find(params[:venue_id]).halls.order(:name)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.json { render json: @halls.to_json }
  end
end
...
```

**application.js:**

```
...
$('select[data-linked=select]').each(function (i) {
  var child_dom_id = $(this).attr('id');
  var parent_dom_id = $(this).data('linked-parent-id');
  var path_mask = $(this).data('linked-collection-path');
  var path_regexp = /:[0-9a-zA-Z_]+:/g;
  var option_value = $(this).data('linked-collection-value');
  var option_label = $(this).data('linked-collection-label');
  var child = $('select#' + child_dom_id);
  var parent = $('#' + parent_dom_id);
  var loading_prompt = $('<option value=\"\">').text('Loading options...');
  var no_items_prompt = $('<option value=\"\">').text('No options available');

  option_value = (option_value === undefined ? "id" : option_value);
  option_label = (option_label === undefined ? "name" : option_label);

  parent.on('change', function () {
    child.attr('disabled', true);
    child.empty().append(loading_prompt);
    child.trigger("chosen:updated")
    if (parent.val()) {
      var path = path_mask.replace(path_regexp, parent.val());
      $.getJSON(path, function (data) {
        child.empty();
        var itemsChanged = false;
        $.each(data, function (i, object) {
          if (object[option_value] === undefined) {
            $.each(object, function (i, subobject) {
              child.append($('<option>').attr('value', subobject[option_value]).text(subobject[option_label]));
              itemsChanged = true;
            });
          } else {
            child.append($('<option>').attr('value', object[option_value]).text(object[option_label]));
            itemsChanged = true;
          }
        });
        child.attr('disabled', !itemsChanged);
        if (!itemsChanged) {
          child.append(no_items_prompt);
        }
        child.trigger("chosen:updated")
      });
    }
  });
});
```